# Saving JTable (in Component) fails when called from a module

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, module, fix-my-code, model

Here is what I am try'n to do. I'm not sure which parts of the code I mite need to copy here, so let me start with some oversimplified pseudo-code to get going.

I have a main component (com_main) with model, Table, etc all working.
From my view.html I can call

```
$modelTU = $this->getModel('TimeUnits');
$modelTU->GetSchedule($date,...);
```

The TU Model

```
public function GetSchedule($date,...){
    $query = self::getQuery();
    $items = $this->_getList((string) $query...);

    if (empty($items)){  //if non found, create new from template
        $templateModel = $this->getModel('Templates');
        $templateModel->createFromTemplate($date);   //create TU's from a tempalte

     }
     return $items;
}
```

The Template Model 
    ...
     public function createFromTemplate($date,...){

```
    //****THIS fails (or =FALSE) if called from module
    //This works fine when called from the component!!
    $modelTU =  JModelLegacy::getInstance('TimeUnit', COM_MODEL_PREFIX); //THIS FAILS

    $query = self::getQueryTempalte(....);
    $items = $this->_getList((string) $query...);
    foreach ($items as $item){
       $valTimeUnit = array(
            'duration' => $item->duration,
            'price' => $item->price
             ...
        );
        $modelTU->save($valTimeUnit);   
        //I also tried store bind here
        $tblTu = $modelTU->getTable();
        $tblTu->bind(valTimeUnit);  //table = False !!!

    }
 }
```

I don't know how else to explain this. The bottom line:
I load timeunits (TU) ... and if for the given date non exist, 
I call a template model to load a set of template units to be cloned into TU's

This works fine when called from within the component

If I import the models via in to the module
require_once( JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_main/models/timeunit.php');
etc

it works, I can LOAD Timeunits if they exist just find

It also calls the templateModel to clone new once until I my marker ****
The final TimeUnit Model ->Save, or ->getTable(); fails

But only when called from the module

What Am I doing wrong / violating any rules? Namespace imports
I don't understand how It can load and work the first two model levels, and then fail to load the last one. 
I already figured I can't use 'JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE' to require files within my component if I want them to work from my module, I use 
'JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_byteitbooking/'.

Any pointers what I mite miss?

Thanks

EDIT: additional code
I made this test, in my timeunit model extending JModelAdmin

```
public function getTable($type = self::THIS_CLASS_NAME, $prefix = COM_TABLE_PREFIX,   $config = array()) {
    dumpMessage("-> admin.MODEL.TimeUnit.getTable()");
    dumpMessage("-> $type,$prefix");
    dump($config,'$config');
    $tb = JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
    dump($tb,'$tb');
    return $tb;
    //return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
}
```

results 1st called from component, 2nd from module ...the vars are resolved correctly

- admin.MODEL.TimeUnit.getTable()
- TimeUnit,ByteitBookingTable
- [array] $config = (empty)
- [ByteitBookingTableTimeUnit object] $tb

VS

- admin.MODEL.TimeUnit.getTable()
- TimeUnit,ByteitBookingTable
- [array] $config = (empty)
- [boolean] $tb = FALSE

Do I have to copy the models/tables into the module in order to use them? Is there some kind of restriction in Joomla I am missing?

Comment: `COM_MODEL_PREFIX` is this constant defined by your component?

Comment: Yes, I was tired of all the strings, so this holds 'ByteitBookingTable'

Comment: Try after passing prefix as string instead of constant. Make sure the required model class is loaded.

Comment: @Gaurav: I updated my code to include my modified GetTable(). As you can see in the results, BOTH times type and prefix are resolved ...yet in one, the table is null

Comment: COM_TABLE_PREFIX, Where is it defined?

Comment: in a file within the component. I also did try using the fixed string names ($type = 'TimeUnit', $prefix = 'ByteitBookingTable'), still nothing

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to include the paths both for model and table:

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_main/models', 'ByteitBookingModel');

$modelTU = JModelLegacy::getInstance('TimeUnit', 'ByteitBookingModel');
$modelTU->addTablePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_main/tables');
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion as soon as I get some free time @Dmirty. I am sure I'm either missing an include, or somewhere it uses a false value.